# What is the meaning of "=min!"

Tags: optimization, notation, quantile, quantile-function

Specifically, it appears in the following definition

$$ \hat\xi_\tau = \inf_\xi \left\{ \xi \in \mathbb{R} \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n \rho_\tau(Y_i - \xi) = \min! \right\} $$

where $\rho_\tau(.)$ is the objective function for a quantile regression. Unfortunately, Roger Koenker **didn't** provide any indication anywhere regarding what the symbols he uses in his book mean. I have never seen that anywhere else, so what does it mean?

It appears at the top of page 69 of **Quantile Regression** (2005), for reference.

Comment: My guess: look at the set of all $\xi \in \mathbb R$ where the form $\sum_{i=1}^n \rho_\tau(Y_i - \xi)$ achieves its minimum.

Comment: I suspect the $!$ may require that to be a unique minimum.

Comment: I agree with Robert, in most instances the $!$ is used to denote the *unique* such object; in this case the unique minimum.

Comment: Why not just write argmin then? Why put inf over $\xi$, but then declare a unique minimal value? I'm assuming that's what he means (the hat usually indicates an estimator in econometrics and I'd write it as argmin if I had to do so). I just don't get what the added details bring besides confusion.

Comment: In other cases, they're using argmin. It seems that unique minimum is the answer since there is a unique minimum here. I don't know if someone should give the answer with a bit of detail so I can assign 'best answer' and others may refer to this question if they ever encounter it.